# How to add gas to a Truffle generated account imported to MetaMask

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

I am a beginner and was building a dapp using truffle unbox react. In my app, I was just taking input of a string and printting it using a simple contract.

Everything is working fine. But, when i give input and set my string. Metamask tab opens and asks for gas payment. I have imported the first one of the 10 private keys generated by truffle in matamask.

But, it has 0 gas. shouldn't it have 100 gas or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have deployed your contracts on a public testnet like Ropsten or Goerli.

You can testnet ETH on your MetaMask account from a testnet faucet:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/

https://goerli-faucet.slock.it/

Comment: I have deployed it on my private network

Comment: Please transfer ETH from your private network genesis accounts to any accounts that are empty. When you launch the network the initial ETH is put somewhere.